# Iterating List<int> in a Anonymous Type

Tags: c#, anonymous-types, ninject-extensions, ninject-interception

I am using Ninject Interception extension to implement SQLLogging. 
I have a variable called 'param' and it is an Anonymous type as it showed in Watch window (See the picture below). When I do `param.ToString()` it returned

```
{Countries = {System.Collections.Generic.List< int >}


var param = invocation.Request.Arguments[0];
```

where invoation is of type Ninject.Extensions.Interception.IInvoation Interface.

What I need to get is a name and its items. So, for this one I want something like "Countries = 36, 124, 826, 840".

How do I iterate through the List to achieve that? Also, notice that the name `Countries` in this case is not known until run-time. It could be something like

```
{Ages = {System.Collections.Generic.List< int >}
```

or

```
{Subjects={System.Collections.Generic.List< string >}
```

[image: object in watch window]

Comment: Anonymous type property can't be declared at runtime, it has to be a compile time thing. How is `params` variable defined?

Comment: Well, make it known at compile-time. Anonymous types are 100% designed for compile-time and generics, there's no point in using them as "generic return value". Stop using anonymous types.

Comment: param is an element of object[ ] and I have inherited this code base so I can't change to other type. The Watch window listed all items in VS. How do I do something similar in c#?

Comment: You'd have to heavily rely on Reflection, it won't be pretty, it won't be fast and won't be easy. So most likely you shouldn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to write your own visualizer for `List<T>`. It will be used for all lists, not only the ones of your anonymous types, but it may still be useful for you.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2zc529c.aspx

Comment: I need to implement this iteration logic within my c# application. I am using Ninject Interceptor to implement SQLLogging and this  proxy class receives object[] and one of element is <Anonymous Type>.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of reflection, looping properties, checking the type and if it is a list, iterate the list.